# .platform/nginx/nginx.conf Does not apply/replace default nginx.conf file in AWS

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have deployed an aws sample app and I have created url redirects within my default /etc/nginx/nginx.conf and my redirects work.

My problem is: when placing in my nginx.conf file within .platform/nginx/nginx.conf, the file does not overwrite the default nginx.conf file.
I have attempted to write scripts in eb extension to move my custom nginx.conf file but this does not work.
FYI: AMI linux 2 ,php version 8.0 +
What do you suggest ?

Comment: I am facing the same issue - have you managed to find a solution?